# Searching ListView that uses ListAdapater, not ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, search, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I have a list view that uses a List Adapter as the adapter to populate the list view. I researched online for a way to add a search for this, but all of them are using ArrayAdapters. Since I'm using a List Adapter, the function `getFilter()` doesn't work. This is my code

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // When user changed the Text
                        adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                            int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
                    }
```

Can someone help me find an alternative way so doing this in a simple way?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in your Adapter like this:

`public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        objectList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            objectList.addAll(objectAsArraylist);
        } else {
            for (Object v : objectAsArraylist) {
                objectList.add(v);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }`

where `objectList` is the list you passed to the adapter, and `objectAsArraylist` is the `objectList` passed to an arraylist.

Then you can call this method on your `onTextChanged`:

`adapter.filter(text)`

Comment: I don't have an arrayList. I have a SimpleAdapter and a ListAdapter. So the `addAll()` and `add()` functions don't work

Comment: You can create one, passing the values you want in the list to the arraylist.

Comment: `List<YourObject> objectAsArraylist = new ArrayList<>(); `
`objectAsArraylist.addAll(objectList);`

Comment: I am still confused in figuring out how to implement your code

Comment: Can you insert you adapter code in you post so i can clarify?

Comment: I have my whole class [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283992/how-to-implement-a-search-for-a-listview-that-uses-listadapater-arraylist-and-h?noredirect=1#comment48710267_30283992) . Can you please take a look? Thanks